# Jquery preload images 1 through 40

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preloading

I'm working on pre loading images and I am trying to load 1 through 40 but its not working :( here is the code:

```
function preload(arrayOfImages){
 $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
  (new Image()).src = this;
 });
};preload(['/img/wallpapers/'images 1 to 40'.jpg']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function preload(arrayOfImages){
 $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
  (new Image()).src = this;
 });

 for(i=1;i<=40;i++)
  preload('/img/wallpapers/'images' + i + '.jpg');
```

Comment: Title says from 1 to 40, so i think for(i=1;i<=40;i++)